# Laravel 9 Validation of Nested Array Fails

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation

I am trying to validate a nested input array in Laravel 9 and having a devil of a time. I have three arrays in the input. Two succeed as expected but the third fails and I cannot find the reason. All the research I have done indicates it should work.

Relevant inputs:

```
<select name="interval[0]" required="">
<input type="number" name="interval_quantity[0]" required="">
<input type="text" name="amount[0]['major']" required="">
<input type="text" name="amount[0]['minor']" required="">
<select name="amount[0]['currency']" required="">
```

Those inputs produce the following payload:

```
interval[0]: yearly
interval_quantity[0]: 1
amount[0]['major']: 30
amount[0]['minor']: 00
amount[0]['currency']: USD
```

My form request validation rules are:

```
  'interval' => ['required', 'array'],
  'interval.*' => ['required', 'string', 'max:30'],
  'interval_quantity' => ['required', 'array'],
  'interval_quantity.*' => ['required', 'integer'],
  'amount' => ['required', 'array'],
  'amount.*' => ['required', 'array:major,minor,currency'],
  'amount.*.major' => ['required', 'integer'],
  'amount.*.minor' => ['required', 'integer'],
  'amount.*.currency' =>['required', 'string', 'max:3']
```

Initially, I did not have the 'amount.*' line and had 'array:major,minor,currency' in the 'amount' line, but in an earlier round of troubleshooting I decided that those keys are not actually in 'amount', they are in 'amount[*]' so I added the 'amount.*' line. Result did not change.

The 'Interval' and 'Interval_quantity' arrays pass those rules and make it to the controller fine. But the 'amount' array produces the following errors:

```
  array(4) {
    ["amount.0"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(30) "The amount.0 must be an array."
    }
    ["amount.0.major"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(37) "The amount.0.major field is required."
    }
    ["amount.0.minor"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(37) "The amount.0.minor field is required."
    }
    ["amount.0.currency"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(40) "The amount.0.currency field is required."
    }
  }
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove ' ' (single quotes) in input name:

```
<input type="text" name="amount[0][major]" required="">
<input type="text" name="amount[0][minor]" required="">
<select name="amount[0][currency]" required="">
```